# AJAX output element not iterating with query results

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an issue where one of my divs in my WHILE statement is not being duplicated. This is an issue because the div contains output from AJAX that is related to each row.

Here is my WHILE statement:

```
<?php
while($row_cat = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$id1=$row_cat['mgap_ska_id'];
$record=$row_cat['mgap_ska_record_type'];
$name=$row_cat['mgap_ska_report_category'];
$growth=$row_cat['total'];

?>

<div class="show" >
  <div class="accButton" id="<?php echo $name;  ?>">
      <span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $record;  ?></span>
      <span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $name;  ?></span>
      <span class="growthcust">$<?php echo $growth;  ?></span>
      <span class="accepted"><a href="#" class="accept" id="<?php echo $id1; ?>" data-order="<?php echo $name; ?>"><input type="button" title="accept" value="Accept" /></a>    </span>
      <span class="decline"><a href="#" class="decline" id1="<?php echo $id1; ?>" data-order1="<?php echo $name; ?>"><input type="button" title="declined" value="Decline" /></a></span>
  </div> 
      <div class="accContent" id="output_element"> </div>//This DIV is only being displayed one time
</div>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

and here is the output should look like:

ROW1
AJAX OUTPUT FOR ROW 1
ROW2
AJAX OUTPUT FOR ROW 2
ROW3
AJAX OUTPUT FOR ROW 3

and here is what it looks like now:
ROW1
AJAX OUTPUT FOR ROW 1
ROW2
ROW3
ROW3

When I click on the other rows the AJAX output changes as required so I know the process to/from is working and data is passing as required, but I cannot get the outout row to iterate with the rest.

Any ideas?

BTW here is the query that AJAX calls:

```
         while($row_cat_sub = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            $item=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_description'];
            $item_num=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_number'];
            $item_type=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_type'];

            ?>  
              //this is being returned via AJAX
              <span><?php echo $item;  ?></span>
              <span><?php echo $item_num;  ?></span>             
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

EDIT: added SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_report_category = '$id' GROUP BY mgap_item_description LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Firstly - you are duplicating that elements ID by the sounds of it, which is against the HTML spec and will likely cause you problems (perhaps might be THE problem).

Comment: Isnt that done anyway during the WHILE statement if the rows are being duplicated? How can I work around it?

Comment: Use an id with the row id appended or just use classes instead